# How to select ALL UICollectionView cells like in the iOS Photos app using Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I can't seem to get this to work for me and I haven't found any other answers to similar questions that work.

I am working with Swift and need to know how to be able to have a "Select All" button in my app select all visible & non-visible cells just like the stock Photos app on iOS.

My app is dealing with photos too, and so each cell has two UIImageViews, one that is the photo in question, and another that is a hidden UIImageView that appears upon selection of an image (it is just a check mark).

The code I've been using (which won't work) is this:

```
        for cell in self.collectionView.visibleCells() as! [ImageCell]{
        if cell.checkMark.hidden{
            cell.checkMark.hidden = false
        }
        else{
            cell.checkMark.hidden = true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's good to understand how the control works. `UICollectionView` and `UITableView` both only create and display enough cells to fit on screen (and maybe a couple more for scroll buffer). This is in order to handle the case where an app may have a large number of data. For example, if a user has 1000 photos, performance would be awful if 1000 were actually displayed on and off screen.

That being said, you should handle selection through models. There are many ways to do this, but one way is:

Have each cell be represented by a custom object that has at least a `photo` and `isSelected` as a property. Every time the user selects or deselects, the cell, simply update the `isSelected` property. In `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`, display the checkmark based on the `isSelected` property. Select all by simply looping through the array and updating that one property, then call `reloadData` to update it for every cell.

Because you updated the array and the `UICollectionView` is based on the array, every cell will be selected as it gets shown on screen.